# How to structure a model database for Gazebo Ignition

Tags: ros2, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to create a model/world database for my Gazebo Ignition projects.
I've created the following folder structure for my database:

```
├─ gazebo-database/
 │   ├─ models/
 │   │   ├─ model1/
 │   │   ├─ model2/
 │   ├─ worlds/
 │   │   ├─ world1/
 │   │   │   ├─ world1.sdf
 │   │   ├─ world2/
```

I'd like to be able to open a world (let's say world1.sdf) using:

```
ros2 launch ros_ign_gazebo ign_gazebo.launch.py ign_args:="-v -r world1.sdf"
```

I tried to set **IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH** env variable to  /gazebo-database but it didn't work.
It seems that the database is not parsed to find the model.
It only works if I set the **IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH**  to /gazebo-database/worlds/world1/
I don't want to have to add all the path to the worlds manually...

Can someone explain me how to do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28230/how-to-structure-a-model-database-for-gazebo-ignition/) by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2022-06-11**:
Do the worlds really need to be in their own subdirectories?

**Comment by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on 2022-06-13**:
No not really, but it would be cleaner to have everything related to a world in its directory.
In this repository, they create a folder for each world: https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2022-06-13**:
The folders in the `gazebo_models` repo are models, not worlds. There's a difference between the two. What you have for the models in your original example should work, but you'd set `IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH` to `/gazebo-detabase/models`. More info here: https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_structure&cat=build_robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

And here: https://github.com/robotology/gym-ignition-models they use python to add the full path to the worlds in **IGN_GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH**.
I'll do something similar then.

---

Originally posted by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) with karma: 3 on 2022-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0